# Undefined method 'email' for nil:NilClass? - Ruby on Rails Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model, controller, rails-activerecord

Ok first of, I just want to say Ive encountered this problem before and its usually a quick fix.. but I am actually confused this time.

I have a simple post application where users can post statuses/images. Im adding the functionality to add comments, however here is the issue i run into:

on my posts show page, i am listing all the comments, as well as ability to add new comment.

POSTS SHOW PAGE:

```
<%if @post.is_status?%>
  <h5><%=@post.user.email%>:</h5>
  <%=@post.body%><br>
  Posted:<%=@post.created_at%><br><hr>
<%else%>
  <h5><%=@post.user.email%>:</h5>
  <%=image_tag @post.body%><br>
  Posted:<%=@post.created_at%><br><hr>
<%end%>

<h6>Comments:</h6>
<%@comments.each do |x|%>
  <%@user = x.user%>
  <%=x.comment%> -<%=@user.email%> <br>
<%end%>

<%=form_for @comment do |x| %>
  <%=x.hidden_field :post_id%>
  <%=x.hidden_field :user_id%>
  <%=x.label :comment%>
  <%=x.text_area :comment%><br>
  <%=x.submit%>
<%end%>
```

my posts show action in the posts controller:

```
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @post.comments.all
    @comment = @post.comments.new(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
```

and finally my create action in my comments controller:

```
 def create
    @comment=Comment.create(params.require(:comment).permit(:comment, :post_id, :user_id))
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "saved"
    else
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "not saved"
    end
  end
```

when the request goes through i get the following from rails log:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lOHcmJJ3ptDiizpt95/1xHQ4GQkcjyHsAfTHiH/23f0Rjds7pI0Ii0XzcZ3UFGCKap7jwvdl7pV8wr+8oNu+mg==", "comment"=>{"post_id"=>"22", "user_id"=>"1", "comment"=>"test123"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment"}
```

So i can see user_id = 1 is being passed.

The output of my post show page gives me:

```
comments:
test123 -#<User:0x007fad5b4311a0>
```

So i can see the user is there!
if i modify my post show page like so:

```
<%=x.comment%> -<%=@user.inspect%> <br>
```

i get the following output:

```
test123 -#<User id: 1, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, profile_picture: nil, created_at: "2015-07-02 03:51:14", updated_at: "2015-07-06 21:34:07", email: "test123@example.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$7irTux0aMTbSXZUyB3Ubbux0MBhF.Z0Ll0QyY8pS1mv...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 12, current_sign_in_at: "2015-07-06 21:34:07", last_sign_in_at: "2015-07-06 21:28:18", current_sign_in_ip: #<IPAddr: IPv6:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff>, last_sign_in_ip: #<IPAddr: IPv6:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff>>
```

So i can see that user.email is valid...

however when i modify post show page as so:

```
<%=x.comment%> -<%=@user.email%> <br>
```

I get

```
 undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

This is strange, I know there is a user, and email is valid for that user, as seen from user.inspect

Any ideas as to why its giving me a nil class error ?

Comment: Can you post your full show page?

Comment: just posted the full page!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like one of the particular `comment` doesn't have ***associated*** *user*. For a quick fix, try the below code.

```
<%= @user.try(:email) %>
```

Comment: it does have a user - I can see it when i go @user.inspect

Comment: @SUPERUSER In your code you are iterating `@comments` and storing `@user` as `x.user`. As `@comments` is a collection of records, it seems a particular `comment` doesn't have a `user` associated.